# The markup must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, sax, well-formed

First off, let me say I am a new to SAX and Java.

I am trying to read information from an XML file that is not well formed.

When I try to use the SAX or DOM Parser I get the following error in response:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

This is how I set up my XML file:

```
<format type="filename" t="13241">0;W650;004;AG-Erzgeb</format>
<format type="driver" t="123412">001;023</format>
   ...
```

Can I force the SAX or DOM to parse XML files even if they are not well formed XML?

Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.
Haythem

Comment: FYI: By definition... If it's not well formed it's **not** XML. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your best bet is to make the XML well-formed, probably by pre-processing it a bit. In this case, you can achieve that simply by putting an XML declaration on (and even that's optional) and providing a root element (which is not optional), like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wrapper>
    <format type="filename" t="13241">0;W650;004;AG-Erzgeb</format>
    <format type="driver" t="123412">001;023</format>
</wrapper>
```

There I've arbitrarily picked the name "wrapper" for the root element; it can be whatever you like.

Comment: I'd just like to add that you don't necessarily need to do that modification on the disk, but that you could do it on the fly by providing a filtering `InputStream`/`Reader`. Especially for big files (or reading XML from a URL) this can be very useful. A `SequenceInputStream` could be useful here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html

Comment: Good posibility.
is not easier to trun out the parse?.

can I turn out the parse() mehtode and overwrite it to ignore the non-well-formed status?

Comment: Haythem: probably not, because the parser is deep within the library and the behavior of such a browser would be undefined (the XML libraries don't know how to handle XML with more than one root element). Doing it this way instantly makes your XML well-formed and **all** XML-aware tools can suddenly handle it just fine (provided you have no other incorrect parts in there).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: using sax or stax you can successfully parse a not well formed xml document until the **FIRST** "well formed-ness" error is encountered.

(I know that this is not of too much help...)

Answer (score 0):

As the DOM will scan you xml file then build a tree, the root node of the tree is like the  as 1 Answer. However, if the Parser can't find the  or even , it can even build the tree. So, its better to do some pre-processing the xml file before parser it by DOM or Sax.