# parsing a big big not well formed file with Java

Tags: java, parsing, file-io

I have to resolve a problem close to parsing a huge file like, 3 GB or higher. Well, the file is structured how a pseudo xml file like:

```
<docFileNo_1>
<otherItems></otherItems>

<html>
<div=XXXpostag>
</html>

</docFileNo>
   ... others doc... 
<docFileNo_N>
<otherItems></otherItems>

<html>
<div=XXXpostag>
</html>

</docFileNo>
```

Surfing the net i have read about some people that have encountered problem to manage files, but they suggest to me, to map a file with NIO.
So i think that the solution is too expansive and could bring me thrown an exception. So i think that my problem is to resolve 2 doutbs:

1. How to read efficiently in time
   the 3 GB text file
2. How to parser
       efficiently the html extract from
       the docFileNoxx, and apply rules to
       the html's tag to extract the post of
   the tag.

So.. I have try to resolve the first question on this way:

1. _reader = new BufferedReader(new
   FileReader(filePath)) // create a
   buffer reader of file
2. _currentLine = _reader.readLine();
   // i iterate the file reading it
   line by line
3. For every line, i append the lines
   to a String variable until encounter
   the tag
4. so with JSOUP and post CSS filter
   i extract the content, and put it on
   file.

Well the process of extraction of 25 MB, on average takes about 88 seconds....
So i would like to perform it.

HOw I could perform my extraction??

Comment: How much of the 3G is actual data (jn the div), and how much structure (docfileno tags etc)? Because you wouldn't need to store all that reproducible stuff in the string.

Comment: Why do you need to append lines **before** you encounter the tag?

Comment: Step 3: don't use string but stringbuilder. String + operator will create a new string each time (if the JVM does not optimize it away, that I don't know for sure).

Comment: @extraneon good point, I missed it, since didn't thought that it can be done **without** using `stringbuilder` :)

Comment: @khachik I actually think that if the concat logic is written inline in the loop that the JVM, or even the compiler, automatically fixes this. But I can't guarantee that. It would be, if not optimized, a good cause for an OutOfMemoryError, as at 3GB the next concat would need about 6GB (old value and new value). And it would cause massive garbage collector overhead in any case.

Comment: @extraneon modern compilers do that, but I always do it explicitly and consider it is a good habit :)

Comment: extraneon ::
The problem is to parsing 3g files, during that processing task, i have extract the content of the pseudo xml structure..I know that i have not save all...

Comment: khachik >> I append into a string because when i parse the file, 3GB, line by line i have string ok?..so with alllines i use the methdo of string .contains("<html")..when I encounter the html's ends tag,like a string HTML, i parse it with JSOUP and with a method select of JSOUP I extract the content of the post inside the html parsed...so for those process..  i have to append the lines append..Now it's more clean??

Comment: @Bomberlatinos9 You can check each line you read (or I didn't get your problem...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't do (pseudo code):

```
String data = "";
for line in file {
    data += line;
}
```

but use a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
for line in file {
    data.append(line);
}
return data.toString();
```

Further, consider walking through the file and create a map with only the interesting parts.
I assume you don't have XML but something which only looks a bit like it, and the example you gave is a fair representation of the content.

```
Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<String,String>(1000);
StringBuilder entryData = null;
for line in file {
  if line starts with "<docFileNo" {
     docFileNo = extract number from line;
  } else if line starts with "<div=XXXpostag>" {
     // Content of this entry starts here
     entryData = new StringBuilder();
  } else if line starts with "</html>" {
     // content of this entry ends here
     // so store content, and indicate that the entry is finished by 
     // setting data to null
     entries.put(docFileNo, entryData.toString);
     entryData = null;
  } else if entryData is not null {
     // we're in an entry as data is not null, so store the line
     entryData.append(line);
  }
}
```

The map contains only entry-sized strings which makes them a bit easier to handle. I think you'd need to adapt it to the true data, but this is something which you could test in about half an hour.

The clue is entryData. it is not only the StringBuilder in which the data of 1 entry is build, but if not-null it also indicates we saw a start entry marker (the div) and if null we saw the end marker `(</html>)` indicating the next lines need not be stored.

I assumed you want to keep the doc number, and the XXXposttag is constant.

An alternative implementation of this logic could be made using the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Comment: Ok. firs of all TANX SO MUCH. I have modified my code following your suggestions.. And all goes better... UNfortunatly the XXXpostag is not constant but, to retrievi the post tag, i have realized a filter that contains some rules that permits me to extract the content of certain cms, like blogger, wordpress..IN fact
there is other problem, that is apply a rule that:
1. recognize the post tag inside looking cms generator.
1.1 recognized the cms generator, looking for a rules for task extraction of content. the rules for al cms are inside a xml..

Comment: My doubt is to understand if is more expensive trasform all cms rules in byte and...for all tag inside xml compare with that bytes of the rules..

Answer (score 1):

For large XML files it is best to use a [SAX](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/when.html) style parser, these don't attempt to build a document object model in memory for the whole XML file. I wouldn't try to read the XML file line by line, I'd call an appropriate method in the SAX implementation. Oracle have a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Comment: How well does a SAX parser handle non-wellformed documents? I read in the question that it might not be well-formed :(

Comment: The issue in the example data appears to be that the div elements are not closed. <div> needs to be transformed to <div/> on the fly. Also the closing docFileNo tags need suffixing. See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499373/the-markup-must-be-well-formed) where Joachim Sauer suggests using a filtering InputStream/Reader for big files that are not well-formed

Comment: OH tankx.... I have read the articles...But How i can modify a 3G file, putting in the top xml declation..after tag wrapper..and end wrapper??
Remember... I have to manage files like 3G...and i have  50 Terabytes of ile.... :(..

Comment: As I understand it, the principle is that you don't modify the file on disk, your program modifies the datastream as it is fed into the SAX parser.

Comment: Could you make an example how it works with STAX?? ora Sax parser??
BEcaus I don't know how to manage the datastream for the purposes of modify the file adding xml tag like suggest to me by the article..
tanx.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to speed up the process if your problem is the disc io part by using a BufferedInputStream with a large buffer - e.g. 256KB in the following example:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath),256*1024)));
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

If the problem is the CPU and you have a multi-core machine you can try to move work into a separate thread.

Comment: unfortunatly, i have a pentium 4 processor with 2.8 GHz..So I have speed up the process of reading the file...but my huge problem is to understand how speed up the process of :
1. keeping the html inside new StringBuilder()
2. so extract in an efficiently way the content of the post inside html structur.
How I have explained before, the process of keeping the post inside html, is done using the HTml parser JSOUP. But i think that Jsoup when process the html keeps so time..