# Producer/Consumer pattern the Java way

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to resolve a problem close to parsing a huge file like, 3 GB or higher. Well, the file is structured how a pseudo xml file like:

```
<docFileNo_1>
<otherItems></otherItems>
<html>
<div=XXXpostag>
</html>

</docFileNo>
   ... others doc... 
<docFileNo_N>
<otherItems></otherItems>

<html>
<div=XXXpostag>
</html>

</docFileNo>

.......
```

In an recent post :"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355107/parsing-a-big-big-not-well-formed-file-with-java", I have encountered an interesting  solution to my problem.. So I have thought to implement my application parser like multithread:

1. After collect in a strinbUilder the text context with a tag  until <\html>, I return the Stringbuilder.
2. After return the Stringbuilder, I extract the text content of html page throught CSS rules. I obtain that with an html parser, JSOUP http://jsoup.org/. After extracted the content of html page, I must to save that content on a file.

So.. Put my attention to the step 1) and 2), I think to separate the sequencial pattern with a multithread way like:

1. After Reading a chunk of the file (line by line until obtain from  .. to  <\html>), I append the line to an Stringbuilder.
2. For an StringBuilder I create a thread that support a code to 
   2.1  Parse the html and extract the text content.
   2.2  Save the text content in a file.

So I have a doubt..

1. How many Threads I must to create ?? Is possible that I must create a thread for all Stringbuilder created?? It don't bring to memory problem??
2. How can I do to obtain the exact number of thread that had worked well??
3. How Can I know how many threads have finished ?? I have to wait that all threads have finished to terminate my work??

For my doubts...the point 1, I don't know how really resolve it. For point 2, I think that i could implement threads like inner class of the class that parsing a file, and so i can have a static counter incremented by all threads that have finished. For the point 3, I think that is similar point 2, but I don't know how to do wait my application....

Someone could me suggest somthing to resolve my doubts??
thanks :)

Comment: I feel the title is somewhat misleading. I thought you're gonna ask something related to messaging or Design Pattern.

Comment: I've done something very similar, parsing huge files by "chunks" and then consuming the chunks using several threads (except that my parser was **very** complicated and hence quite slow).  Basically what works well is to adapt the number of threads to the number of (virtual) CPU available.  If you have a dual-core CPU, it's mostly pointless to have two or more consumer threads.  If, on the other hand, you have 16 virtual cores, you may want about 16 consumer threads.

Comment: one way to know how many threads have finished is to put 'n' *poison pills* in your chunks queue and to use, say, a *CountDownLatch* that you decrement everytime a poison pill is read.  You can read about poison pills in the excellent *Java Concurrency In Practice* book.

Comment: @SpoonBender: I found your Suggestion interesting.So, I would like to know if you could me explain a way, how I can adapt the number of threads to the number of (virtual) CPU available...Unlikely I have a Pentium 4 2.8 GHz with 2GB of ram...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a decent, efficient parser, it should be able to parse the data as fast as you can read it.  I suggest you look at make sure this is the case and you will be able to use one thread (possibly a separate one to do the reading)

3 GB isn't that huge. You should be able to read/parse it in under a minute.  Much of that time will be just reading the file off disk.  The cost is likely to be what you do with the parsed information and that is that will be worth passing on to one or more additional threads.

To chain data between two threads (one for read, one for processing) you can use either an Exchanger or PipedOutputStream/PipedInputStream.  The exchanger is more efficient but the Piped stream is easier to integrate with a parser.

Comment: If there is a down vote, I would like to learn why it was done.  Any up vote I can learn from also welcome.

Comment: @peter- Can't help you with the downvote, but 3G is a freaking huge text file in my world.  And it would take a long time to read it.  Some parsers (the type that like to hold the tree in memory) would choke on it.

Comment: For my purposes 3GB is too huge, because  the all operation that i have explained here it must takes few seconds :(...because a have to analyse more than 50 TERA of documents like that I have describe before.

Comment: @ALL: WIth the sequencial step, I takes about 88 seconds to do all!!So for that reason, I thought to implement all like multithreading :(

Comment: How fast is your disk? A typical disk can read at about 40 MB/s so a 3 GB file takes about 75 seconds to read.  The fastest way to read it is sequentially. The OS should detect you are reading sequentially and make sure the data you need is being read before you ask for it.  For this reason adding a reading thread won't always help much.  The only way to make this faster is to have a better understanding of your hardware and possibly get faster hardware.  Not all problems can be solved by software.

Comment: If you have 50 TB of disk, I assume you have more than 1 disk.  You can try to ensure that you are reading/processing a file from each disk concurrently.  This will slow down how long it take a single file to be processes but will speed up processing for all your files.  Never the less, you should do a disk test and see what is the fastest you can read all your data once.  Java/C/whatever won't do any better that what your hardware is capable of. If you can read/parse you data in twice the time it takes to read all your data, you have done well. IMHO.

Comment: A good server can handle about 300 MB/s of disk IO. I suggest you might be able to get one server to read 50,000,000 MB in about 45 minutes. And about the same again if you are parsing the data.  As I have suggested you could easily spend much more time doing something useful with that data.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey : I have  an noteBook PEntium 4 2.8 GHz, the disk is an SAMSUNG HM 120JC, Capacity 120 GB,Interface  UDMA 100,Buffer DRAM Size  8 MB. Attually i have tested my program with a file about 25 MB, structured like a pseudo-Xml. I can't parse it like a normal XML File because the file doesn't contain a xml structure. So i have modified that file to become it. Unlikely when i try to parse it i have an exception, because on the structure html tag contains tags or somthing that makes throws an exception.So it's so difficult for me to understand the best way to realize a sofware..

Comment: I have to assume you cannot process 50 TB of data on a laptop. ;)  A laptop hard drive might sustain 20 MB/s. (They are built for small size and power requirements, not speed)  If you have bugs in your code that is another, unrelated issue. You need to fix those bugs first, (perhaps the topic of another question) but you need to be realistic about what your hardware can achieve.